# switching images on click

Tags: jquery, image, toggle

Hi what i've done work but i'm interested if there is any option to do it in a better way because my solution seems to me very primitive.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){



var montaz = $(".montaz");
var doradztwo = $(".doradztwo");
var produkcja = ("$.produkcja");

montaz.hide();
doradztwo.hide();

$(".montaz1").on("click", function(){
  $(".doradztwo").hide();
  $(".produkcja").hide();
  $(".montaz").show();
});


$(".doradztwo1").on("click", function(){
  $(".produkcja").hide();
  $(".montaz").hide();
  $(".doradztwo").show();
});



$(".produkcja1").on("click", function(){
  $(".montaz").hide();
  $(".doradztwo").hide();
  $(".produkcja").show();
});

 });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgaQOy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example have a function like this:

```
var images = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3'];
var currentImage = 0;
function showNewImage(newImage)
{
    currentImage = newImage;
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
    {
        if (i == currentImage)
        {
            $(images[i]).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(images[i]).hide();
        }
    }
}
```

And then for each image do:

```
$("imageX").on("click", function() {showNewImage(2);});
```

This way you can have as many images as you want.